# Make new AJAX request on ng-click AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have done this HTML for weather search by `inputCity` and when it returns an array, I want to give people a choice to choose from a list:

```
    <form class="form-container" ng-submit="submitForm(inputCity)">
        <input class="input-field" type="text" ng-model="inputCity" placeholder="City">
        <input class="button-style" type="submit" value="Show Weather">
    </form>
    <table class="cities-table" ng-if="isArray">
        <tr ng-repeat="data in cityArray" ng-click="inputCity=='zmw:{{data.zmw}}'">
            <td>{{data.city}} in {{data.country_name}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

My js file:

```
.controller('WeatherController', [
    '$scope',
    'Weather',
    function($scope, Weather) {
        /* TODO: implement */
        $scope.weatherData = [];
        $scope.submitForm = function(inputCity){
            Weather.getWeather(inputCity).success(function(data){
                $scope.isArray = angular.isArray(data.response.results);
                $scope.cityArray = data.response.results;
```

and the link in factory:

```
        getWeather : function(inputCity) {
            return $http({
                url: 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/KEY/conditions/q/' + inputCity + '.json',
                method: 'GET'
            })
        }
```

When array comes, can I do that on `ng-click` it chooses a city name (person can use zmw:{{data.zmw}} instead of inputCity or real city name in search field as that info comes with array) and send an AJAX request?

Making it more clear:

I have made a form with input (where should be written city name) and a search button. When Button is clicked weather information appears below. But when person types in a city, which is not the only one with the same name in the world, like for San Francisco (there is 10 of them - in Argentina, US and so on), then weather API returns array of all possible cities instead of weather information. I made it to that point, where if array is returned, it displays all the cities that API returned. What I want to do now is when person clicks on one of the displayed city, `ng-click` triggers the same AJAX call but with good search input ( zmw:{{data.zmw}} works fine ). Maybe I should do antoher function for that, but then it shows some errors?

Comment: Question is not clear. Explain problem in more detail

Comment: I wrote a little more details, hope that helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the click event to trigger the AJAX call by changing this line

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in cityArray" ng-click="inputCity=='zmw:{{data.zmw}}'">
```

with

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in cityArray" ng-click="submitForm('zmw:' + data.zmw)">
```

Comment: Thanks, so simple but helped so much!:)